# Javascript setTimeOut - is it asyncronous in nested function?

Tags: javascript

I currently have a single javascript function - in simple terms it does 3 tasks:

Task A
Task B
Task C

These 3 tasks are resusable in their own right, so my thoughts are to split the function like this:

```
$(".sel").click(function (e) {

    functionA(e);
    functionB(e);
    functionC(e);
});
```

However the main function contains a setTimeout function which halts the click event before redirecting the link after everything else has finished (just a half second delay). The question I have is if I abstract this code out and put it in say functionA, will that stop functionB running until the wait is over, or will B and C run straight off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one is the _main function_?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: function B and C will run straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 'busy waiting' in javascript, execution will continue after the setTimeout call, and functions B and C will run in order *(presuming your function A is the main function you mentioned)*. When they have finished their operations **and** the timeout is up, execution will jump to the delayed function which you dispatched from function A.

For a description on these general concepts, see this MDN article on Javascript's [concurrency model and event loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: Sorry, just so I'm clear - is it A (wait), B, C - proceed or A, B, C wait complete - proceed?

Comment: The second case. *Waiting*, per se, is not really an activity (unlike A,B or C), it's just a delay before some other activity. During this (wait) any other activity can happen, but no other activity can happen during B, for example. Not sure if that's clear.

Comment: That's great it means I can do what I need to do more efficienty. Thanks for the help.